# table td nth-last-child(even)

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-tables

Here is my table it's hiking trip table:

```
<table class="table-done">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Day</th>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>AB</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Distance</th>
      <th>Hiking time</th>
      <th>Time between</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Fist Day</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>Garbh Bheinn and Belig</td>
      <td>10km</td>
      <td>6hrs</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>1hrs 20min</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Fist Day</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>D</td>
      <td>Neist Point Lighthouse</td>
      <td>2km</td>
      <td>1hrs</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>26min</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>First Day</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>E</td>
      <td>Dunvegan castle</td>
      <td>0km</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I would like to fill every table pane labelled as "Time between" to blue color
so the pane with 1hrs 20min, 26min this should be blue but not the Title "Time between"
I tried:

```
.table-done td:nth-last-child(even){
  background-color:blue;
}
```

but this doesn't work
Could you help me out please. Thank you :)

Comment: What do you mean by "*it doesn't work*"? Your CSS should not style the cell with the text of `"time between"`, since it's a `<th>` not a `<td>`.

Comment: So only those two cells in the time between column should have the CSS applied?

Comment: yes as you're saying @j08691 just those two cells should be blue

Comment: So like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/8goex2zu/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.table-done tr:nth-child(even) td:last-child{
    background-color:blue;
  }
```

```html
<table class="table-done">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Day</th>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>AB</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Distance</th>
                        <th>Hiking time</th>
                        <th>Time between</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Fist Day</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>B</td>
                        <td>Garbh Bheinn and Belig</td>
                        <td>10km</td>
                        <td>6hrs</td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>1hrs 20min</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Fist Day</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>D</td>
                        <td>Neist Point Lighthouse</td>
                        <td>2km</td>
                        <td>1hrs</td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>26min</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>First Day</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>E</td>
                        <td>Dunvegan castle</td>
                        <td>0km</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

I believe this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little unclear EXACTLY what behavior you want. If you want the entire `time-between` column to have a background except for the header, the following code will work.

```css
.table-done td:last-child {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<table class="table-done">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Day</th>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>AB</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Distance</th>
      <th>Hiking time</th>
      <th>Time between</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Fist Day</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>Garbh Bheinn and Belig</td>
      <td>10km</td>
      <td>6hrs</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>1hrs 20min</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Fist Day</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>D</td>
      <td>Neist Point Lighthouse</td>
      <td>2km</td>
      <td>1hrs</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>26min</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>First Day</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>E</td>
      <td>Dunvegan castle</td>
      <td>0km</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```